# Is drop rate from monsters affected by the relative levels of the party vs the monster?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

Title says it all, I'm having trouble getting a certain piece of loot from aqua nebula on the bionis leg to reconstruct colony 6 (so I can get a mobile gem furnace). I killed like 5 of them, am I just out of luck and I'll never be able to progress because I am grossly overlevel. Aqua nebula being level 17 and my party ~34.

Answer (score 2):

Loot chance depends only on enemy and loot itself. If you are talking about [Light Rain Element](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Rain_Element), its chance is 20% drop from wooden chest, so there is nothing surprising in not getting this item from 5 enemies.

Also, if you are out of luck, you can always try to find NPC, which trades this item.